# Fatal error: Call to a member function getCode() on a non-object in Customer/Model/Session.php

Tags: magento-1, magento-enterprise, fatal-error

I have done a multi-website setup in Magento. The second website is configured in a sub folder and is accessible using the folder name as in the URL path.

Site 1 - http://192.165.3.193/ 
Site 2 - http://192.165.3.193/fvm/

I could see at times the following error popping up randomly in any page, this error disappears when I refresh the same page again. It is hard to reproduce this error as it just appears and doesn't come again for quite some time.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getCode() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
```

To add further

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsite()->getCode()
```

is the code which gives the error